# Why Does Python.exe Stop Responding?

Tags: python, pygame, trigonometry

Why and when does Python.exe stop responding?

Today I was playing around with python/pygames, and making a sine/cosine wave graph. While trying to display the X-Position (int xPos), I used this statement:

```
    while xPos < WINDOW_WIDTH:
        stats1 = FONT1.render('X-Position: ' + str(xPos), True, BLACK, BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        stats1Rect = stats1.get_rect()

        stats1Rect.left = 100
        stats1Rect.bottom = 100

        DISPLAY.blit(stats1, stats1Rect)
```

Note: Constants BLACK, BACKGROUND_COLOR, etc. are all predefined. The while statement is in the main application loop

The 'xPos' integer is tracked and added to as the graph moves, and I want to constantly update the xPos integer to display where the graph is at on the x-axis.

So, when I run the program, it is black and stops responding. Without the while statement, everything works as usual, with no errors. I was wondering what maybe caused this and if there was a solution, whether it be placement of code or a different way of displaying.

Comment: ummmm... where are you updating xpos?

Comment: the while statement is the updater - while the xPos is less than the window width, update the text of 'stats1' and blit it. It just doesn't run - it crashes

Comment: Does xpos ever change so that the loop can be broken? It sounds like a simple infinite loop error...

Comment: The xPos is stopped and reset after it hits the window edge. The xPos is incremented by 0.76 every frame (160FPS)

Comment: So you are incrementing xpos, an integer variable, by a float value? That probably isn't going to work.

Comment: Oh I'm comparing two different types. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Wait - I can't really change the xPos to increment an integer, and when it increases by a float it works. I tried changing the variable to int(xPos) to get the int and compare to int WINDOW_WIDTH but there was no change. Kept crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you increment xpos, an integer variable, you are trying to increment it by a float value. Therefore you are comparing two different types, the value of xpos is never incremented, so the loop is infinite causing a runtime error.

Comment: Everything works without the while statement. If I do not constantly update the text it just writes to the screen the float, even though I increment an int with a float so I don't think the comparing different data types is why its crashing

Comment: Are you certain that you update xpos **in** while loop?